# How to get Original value from RGB in java

Tags: java

I create RGB from `320` number. I got following
output:

```
-16776896
```

I wrote this code

```
Color c=new Color(320);
System.err.println(c.getRGB());
System.out.println(c.getRed()+" "+c.getGreen()+" "+c.getBlue()+" "+c.getAlpha());
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Now I want to retrive `320` value from this `-16776896`. what should i do?

Comment: What Color you are using ? java.awt.Color or org.eclipse.swt.graphipcs.Color or other ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.out.println(c.getRGB() & 0x00ffffff);
```

The input is bitwise `OR`d with `0xFF000000` in the constructor of `Color`. This is the inverse operation.

Actually, it is impossible to get the original value if it is negative or bigger than `16777215`.

Comment: You could elaborete your answer. That expalin what is really goin on. To be hones is only the reading of JavaDoc of java.awt.Color for that constructor. ;-).